# by default selected first color in color swatches in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have **color swatches** in around products I want get selected first color by default in magento2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBX7L.png as you can see in the image color, are shown I want to keep the first color by default
code to display color swatches

```
<?php 
                        if($_item->getTypeId() == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE){
                            $swatchBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable")->setTemplate("Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml");
                            echo $swatchBlock->setProduct($_item)->toHtml();                           
                        }

                     ?>
```

jquery code

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
        if(swatchLength >= 1){
            if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
                $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
            }
        }   
    });
```

});

Comment: use jquery  do trigger click on first swatch

Comment: <script>
require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         
            var swatchLength = $('.swatch-attribute').length;
            if(swatchLength >= 1){
                if($('.swatch-attribute').hasClass("color")){
                    $('.swatch-option').first().trigger('click');
                }
            }   
        });
 });
</script> i have wriiten this code

Comment: use setTimeout function

Comment: i have added jquery code but it is not working

Comment: Before asking a new question you should accept the previous answers,

Comment: Which previous answer

Answer (score 1):

Please try once below,

```
var selectswatch = this.element.find('.' + this.options.classes.attributeClass + ' .' + this.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper);
$.each(selectswatch, function (index, item) {
                        var swatchOption = $(item).find('div.swatch-option').first();
                        if (swatchOption.length && !$(item).find('div.swatch-option').hasClass('selected')) {
                            swatchOption.trigger('click');
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      you can just add:        
        
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                         $('.swatches-container .swatch-img, .swatches-container .swatch-span').first().trigger('click');
              });
    </script>
```

If not work change the classes used accordingly !!